# How do I improve my Python code about heap sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I tried to write a heap sort program myself for [Leetcode 217. Contains Duplicate](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) as below rather than using Python built-in sort method. Leetcode should accept heap sort method, but for some reasons I don't know, although my heap sort program works well, I still got the runtime rejection from Leetcode. Can anyone help?

**Solved, below code is re-edited using Floyd algorithm to initialize heap and has passed Leetcode**

```
def heapsort(nums):

    def swap(i, j):

        nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]


    def sift(start, size):

        l = (start << 1) + 1 # Do not forget () for <<
        r = l + 1
        largest = start
        if l <= size - 1 and nums[start] < nums[l]:
            largest = l
        if r <= size - 1 and nums[largest] < nums[r]:
            largest = r   
        if largest != start:
            swap(start, largest)
            sift(largest, size)


    size = len(nums)

    # Initialize heap (Floyd Algorithm)
    end = (size >> 1) - 1
    while end >= 0:
        sift(end, size)
        end -= 1
    swap(0, size - 1)
    size -= 1

    # Heapify recursively
    while size > 1:
        sift(0, size)
        swap(0, size - 1)
        size -= 1
```

Comment: this belongs on codereview

Comment: Sorry, but what's coderview? A module on Stackoverflow or what?@naomik

Comment: Sorry, I should've linked. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NicholasLiu: Does your code work on not? *my heap sort program works well* seems to contradict very much with *got the runtime rejection from Leetcode*. Working code should be posted on codereview for review. Broken code should be posted on Stack Overflow for help fixing it.

Comment: @Matt I improved my code and just edited my post (simply copy all and paste to Leetcode 217 you will know all). But this time, I still get the **Time Limit Exceeded** error. My heap sort code is able to sort list in ascending order, so I guess it's either because there's somewhere not very efficient, or _O(nlogn)_ is still considered too slow for Leetcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does way too much. You're rebuilding the entire heap with every item that you remove. So what should be an O(n log n) algorithm is instead O(n^2).

Essentially, your code is doing this:

```
while array is not empty
    rearrange array into a heap
    extract the smallest item
```

Rearranging the heap takes, at best, O(n) time. And extracting the smallest takes O(log n). So your algorithm is O(n^2 + n log n).

Actually, your method of building the heap from the bottom up is O(n log n) in itself. So your heap sort algorithm is actually O((n+1)*(n log n)). In any case, it's a highly sub-optimal algorithm.

The idea behind heap sort is that you arrange the array into a heap *one time*. That is an O(n) operation. The algorithm is pretty simple:

```
for i = heap.length/2 downto 1
    siftDown(i)
```

This is called [Floyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap), after its inventor.

Note that we start in the middle of the array and sift *down*. The idea is that the last n/2 items are leaf nodes, so they can't sift down, anyway. By starting at n/2 and working backwards, we can heapify the entire array in O(n) time.

After the array is arranged into a heap, we do the following:

```
while heap is not empty
    output the item at heap[0]
    move the item at the end of the heap to heap[0]
    reduce the count of items by 1
    siftDown(0)
```

The item at heap[0] is the smallest item remaining in the heap, so we output it. Then, there's no need to rebuild the entire heap. All you have to do is take the last item in the heap, place it at the top, and sift it down into position. The rest of the heap remains valid.

Making those changes should reduce the running time, although I don't know if that's going to make your code acceptable. There is another way to check for duplicates. It requires O(n) extra space, but it's faster than sorting.

The idea is to create a hash table and then go through the array, checking if the item is in the hash table. If not, add it. If it's already in the table, then it's a duplicate. As Harold pointed out, Python has a [set](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html) type that makes this kind of thing easy to do.

Comment: You're right (and thanks for the long post). So I just edited my code, I first build the heap as before from the list, this takes log(1) + log(2)+...+log(n)~nlog(n); next every time I remove the top element, and replaced it with the last element of the heap, and **rather than rebuild the heap as the initialization that takes nlog(n)**, I should **sift down** the new top element as you said.

Comment: So here's the point, during the **sift down** process, my algorithm is each level down, I just compare the nodes on the triangle (the top node triangle is my new top element), which then takes 2*log(n-1) at worst when the new top element touches the bottom. So now my whole sorting time is nlog(n)+2log(n-1)+2log(n-2)+...+2log(1)~3nlog(n)~nlog(n). Unfortunately, my program is still rejected for **Time Limit Exceeded**.

Comment: Yeah I know hash and set is better with only O(n), I code heap sort only for fun.

Comment: @NicholasLiu: that's better, but you can build the initial heap in O(n) time using Floyd's Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of heap sort, consider [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) python module. It exists for this very purpose - provide an implementation of the heap queue algorithm. It isn't designed not very conveniently, but there are handy [wrappers](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502295-heap-a-heapq-wrapper-class) - you can google it yourself.

Speaking of finding duplicates, any `n log(n)` sorting algorithm shouldn't be efficient enough. Take a look at the python [set](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html) builtin!